# Blender to Unity: Object shifting positions

Tags: blender, unity-game-engine

I have a model that I created in Blender. I then created a bow and arrow and then parented it to the hand bone of the model so that it moves with the hand. When I use the .blend file in Unity, however,the bow and arrow shifts to some other position away from where it is supposed to be. I'm not entirely sure how Unity and Blender's co-ordinate systems differ so it might be that but I haven't really had this problem with other models before. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Ok, so I've figured out what the problem is but I have no idea how to fix it (apologies for my poor modelling practices in advance because i'm fairly new to this)

This is my model in pose position:

[image]

This is my model in rest position:

[image]

I connected the bow to the skeleton by clicking on the bow rig > shift clicking on the hand bone > CNTRL+P > to bone. This works fine as the bow now moves with the skeleton and I can do whatever I need in the NLA editor.

Now, the issue is, when I use the .blend file in Unity, the bow is in the rest position of my model even though the skeleton is in pose position and performing the actions (so the bow is floating on the side).

I've tried connecting it differently. If I connect the bow instead of the bow rig to the model, then it is in the correct position in unity but then the bow rig detaches and so the bow animations don't play.

I've also thought the problem would be solved if I make the the current pose position my rest position but when I do that, the mesh reverts to the old rest position and moves very weirdly with the skeleton. Here is that pic:

[image]

I would really, really appreciated any help with this as it's been hindering my progress for the past few days.

Comment: did you export as obj first?

Comment: No, I've been using the .blend files directly.

Comment: This is a huge pain. It's likely that your problem is: in your modeling program, you have to set the "center" of the overall model. You'd need to ask a "Blender" expert how to do that. If you use say Cheetah3D for modeling, there's basically a button "reset center"

Comment: Updated the post. Sorry for only posting the pictures now because i'm actually doing this at work xD.

Answer (score 1):

This method describes saving the hierarchical assignment of a handheld object until after the character and animations are exported to unity.  The weapon is imported separately in Unity and then assigned as a child to the relevant bone at that time.

[Assigning a handheld object to a blender generated character.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/527259/weapons-for-3d-character.html)